# What is the relation between the classes R, RE coRE, as opposed to P,NP,coNP

Tags: turing-machines, np

I am trying to understand the relation between these classes of languages. 
Can someone do some order in my way of thinking of this? For example, if i take the language HAMPATH = {: G has a hamiltonion path}. I know this is in NP and also NP hard. Does this teach me anything about being in R, RE coRE? is there any connection between them?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question. It is a question about the theory of computation.

Comment: Maybe you should ask here: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If you have a word W and a language L, and you can decide whether or not W is in L, then L is Recursive, regardless of the complexity of how to determine whether W is in L (P or NP or otherwise). P/NP/etc are measures of how much time it takes to get to an answer. R/RE/etc are measures of the *possibility* of getting an answer at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All problems in **P**, **NP**, and co-**NP** are decidable, so all of these classes are strict subsets of **R**. It's known that **R** is a strict subset of both **RE** and co-**RE** and, furthermore, that **R** = **RE** ∩ co-**RE**.

There's a nice intuitive connection between these classes. The definitions of **R**, **RE**, and co-**RE** can essentially be described as

- **R** languages are languages that can be decided.
- **RE** languages are languages that have verifiers.
- co-**RE** languages are languages whose complements are in **RE**.

The definitions of **P**, **NP**, and co-**NP** are

- **P** languages are languages that can be decided *in polynomial time*.
- **NP** languages are languages that have verifiers *that run in polynomial time*.
- co-**NP** languages are languages whose complements are in **NP**.

In a sense, you can go from one class of languages to the other by adding or removing a polynomial-time restriction. (This also helps explain the containments).